# re-populate a directive array reactively in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array defined in my data() which gets populated through a custom directive in its bind hook as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
el: '#showingFilters',
name: "Filters",
data() {
    return {
        country: '' // v-modelled to a <select>
        states: [],
    }
},
directives: {
    arraysetter: {
        bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
            vnode.context[binding.arg] = Object.keys(el.options).map(op => el.options[op].value);
        },
    },
},
methods: {
    countryChangeHandler() {
        this.states.splice(0)
        fetch(`/scripts/statejson.php?country=${this.country}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
                res.states.forEach( (element,i) => {
                    Vue.set(this.states, i, element.urlid)
                });
            })
    },
}
```

The problem starts when I want to re-populate the `states` array in the `countryChangeHandler()` method (when `@change` happens for the country select tag).
I used `splice(0)` to make the array empty first and I have then used `Vue.set` to make the re-population reactive, but Vue still doesn't know about it!!! The array has the correct elements though! I just don't know how to make this reactive.

PS: I searched to do this without `forEach` but `$set` needs an index.

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Not really sure what the motivation for having a custom directive is since you only show part of your code.  Unless you really need a custom directive, try just updating ```this.states = res.states```.  You could then possibly move your 'map' functionality to a computed property.  If you don't get it resolved, at some point consider creating a CodeSandbox.

Comment: Not all countries have states

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work and maintain reactivity.

1. You should be able to replace the entire array without using `splice` or `set`.
2. I have used a closure to capture `this` because sometimes the fetch call interferes with the `this` reference, even inside a lambda expression.

```js
countryChangeHandler() {
        this.states = []
        const that = this
        fetch(`/scripts/statejson.php?country=${this.country}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
                that.states = res.states.map(it=>it.urlid)              
            })
    },
```